# vertically align element in td element using flexbox

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I vertically center the element/text in a table data`td` element, which fills the entire height of its parent table row `tr`? I figure flexbox is the best approach here.

Here's what I've tried so far: https://jsfiddle.net/3tr0cn4s/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need flex for this: Since it's a table cell, it's enough to add

```
.table > tbody > tr > td.cell {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1jp53m1q/1/

(The long selector is necessary to overwrite an existing rule that aligns cell contents at the top)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code below:

```css
td.cell {
    padding: 0 !important;
    line-height: 100% !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Molecule</th>
      <th>Rank</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell"><span>CO<sub>2</sub></span></td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>23</option>
          <option>24</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell"><span>SO<sub>4</sub></span></td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>23</option>
          <option>24</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Normally don't like to specify`!important` anywhere in my css. This works though thanks

Comment: I agree, I was just trying to point out what properties you need to remove.